# Como saber la versión del APK de HMS Core?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Estoy intentando conocer la versión de HMS Core APK para saber si la versión instalada soporta las nuevas características del Map Kit. Estoy probando con este código

```
Log.d("HMS", "Current HMS Core version: " + HuaweiApiAvailability.getServicesVersionCode());
```

Pero me devuelve el código 30000100, cuando en los ajustes se ve que tengo la versión 5.0.1.307.

¿Cómo puedo saber la versión de HMS que tiene instalada el usuario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El API HuaweiApiAvailability.getServicesVersionCode() devuelve la versión mínima de HMS soportada por el dispositivo, para conocer la versión de HMS instalada se debe usar el siguiente código:

```
try {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("com.huawei.hwid", 0);
    Log.d("HMS", "Current HMS Core version: " + packageInfo.versionName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```